# Change the destination filename/location in distcp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, distcp

I have a number of files in a folder in hdfs with their names having a format filename.yyyy-mm-dd-hh.machinename.gz in hdfs. I need to transfer these to s3 but I want to put them at yyyy/mm/dd/hh/filename.yyyy-mm-dd-hh.machinename.gz (this would be the object name since s3 has a flat structure) under the bucket that I specify. The distcp command can transfer files from hdfs to s3 but is there an option to do the above? If not how can I extend distcp to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

**Note that:** This is not a solution, but just a hint.

I don't know the exact answer and also don't have a S3 instance to actually try on it. But here is AWK way of pre-processing the file names and copying files inside a specific directory structure. The command below is written considering local Linux file system:

Initial directory content:

```
user@machine:~/path/to/input$ find
 ./filename.yyyy-mm-dd-hh.machinename.gz
 ./filename.2016-12-10-08.machinename.gz
 ./filename.2015-12-10-08.machinename.gz
 ./filename.2015-10-10-08.machinename.gz
 ./filename.2015-10-11-08.machinename.gz
```

Command for copying files inside a specific directory structure:

```
user@machine:~/path/to/input$ ls | awk -F"." '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4}' | awk -F"-" '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7}' | awk -F" " '{PATH=$2"/"$3"/"$4"/"$5; FNAME=$1"."$2"-"$3"-"$4"-"$5"."$6"."$7; system("mkdir -p "PATH); system("cp "FNAME" "PATH); }'
```

Final directory content after command execution:

```
 ./filename.yyyy-mm-dd-hh.machinename.gz
 ./yyyy
 ./yyyy/mm
 ./yyyy/mm/dd
 ./yyyy/mm/dd/hh
 ./yyyy/mm/dd/hh/filename.yyyy-mm-dd-hh.machinename.gz

 ./filename.2016-12-10-08.machinename.gz
 ./2016
 ./2016/12
 ./2016/12/10
 ./2016/12/10/08
 ./2016/12/10/08/filename.2016-12-10-08.machinename.gz

 ./filename.2015-12-10-08.machinename.gz
 ./2015
 ./2015/12
 ./2015/12/10
 ./2015/12/10/08
 ./2015/12/10/08/filename.2015-12-10-08.machinename.gz

 ./filename.2015-10-11-08.machinename.gz
 ./2015/10
 ./2015/10/11
 ./2015/10/11/08
 ./2015/10/11/08/filename.2015-10-11-08.machinename.gz

 ./filename.2015-10-10-08.machinename.gz
 ./2015/10/10
 ./2015/10/10/08
 ./2015/10/10/08/filename.2015-10-10-08.machinename.gz
```